# Define workOnSubpart via CASE not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to make the layout of the frontend depend on the `backend_layout` value. This is my TypoScript:

```
temp {
  layout = CASE
  layout {
    key.field = backend_layout
    key.ifEmpty.data = levelfield:-2, backend_layout_next_level, slide

    default = LAYOUT_ONECOLUMN
    1 = LAYOUT_ONECOLUMN
    2 = LAYOUT_GALLERYTOP
  }

  pageContent = TEMPLATE
  pageContent {
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/templates/index.html
    workOnSubpart < temp.layout
    marks {
      COLUMN0 < styles.content.getLeft
      COLUMN1 < styles.content.get
      COLUMN2 < styles.content.getRight
      COLUMN3 < styles.content.getBorder
    }
  }
}

page = PAGE
page {
  10 < temp.pageContent
}
```

And this is the corresponding html-excerpt:

```
<!-- ###LAYOUT_ONECOLUMN### begin -->
    EINSPALTIG ;)
<!-- ###LAYOUT_ONECOLUMN### end -->

<!-- ###LAYOUT_GALLERYTOP### begin -->
###COLUMN0###

<div class="grid2">
    ###COLUMN1###
</div>

<aside class="grid1">
    ###COLUMN2###
</aside>
<!-- ###LAYOUT_GALLERYTOP### end -->
```

The result is a blank page. Why is this not working? For debugging purposes, I did the following:

```
temp {
  layout = CASE
  layout {
    key.field = backend_layout
    key.ifEmpty.data = levelfield:-2, backend_layout_next_level, slide

    default = TEXT
    default.value = LAYOUT_ONECOLUMN
    1 = TEXT
    1.value = LAYOUT_ONECOLUMN
    2 = TEXT
    2.value = LAYOUT_GALLERYTOP
  }
}

page = PAGE
page {
  10 < temp.layout
}
```

This prints "LAYOUT_GALLERYTOP" to the page, as expected.

A second test I did:

```
temp {
  pageContent = TEMPLATE
  pageContent {
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/templates/index.html
    workOnSubpart = LAYOUT_GALLERYTOP
    marks {
      COLUMN0 < styles.content.getLeft
      COLUMN1 < styles.content.get
      COLUMN2 < styles.content.getRight
      COLUMN3 < styles.content.getBorder
    }
  }
}

page = PAGE
page {
  10 < temp.pageContent
}
```

This also yielded the desired layout, but of course does not response to changing the backend_layout value in the backend.

Why can I not define the `workOnSubpart` value via a `CASE`. Is there a solution or workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE is a cObject, therefore you need to use the stdWrap cObject feature:

```
temp {
  layout = CASE
  layout {
    key.field = backend_layout
    key.ifEmpty.data = levelfield:-2, backend_layout_next_level, slide

    default = TEXT
    default.value = LAYOUT_ONECOLUMN
    1 = TEXT
    1.value = LAYOUT_ONECOLUMN
    2 = TEXT
    2.value = LAYOUT_GALLERYTOP
  }

  pageContent = TEMPLATE
  pageContent {
    template = FILE
    template.file = fileadmin/templates/index.html
    workOnSubpart.cObject < temp.layout
    marks {
      COLUMN0 < styles.content.getLeft
      COLUMN1 < styles.content.get
      COLUMN2 < styles.content.getRight
      COLUMN3 < styles.content.getBorder
    }
  }
}
```